# How to keep div x to the right of img its currently overlayed on using position absolute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create this (Black represents the div in my current code):

[image]

Currently the div is not consistent in its placement, like I would like it to be (I would like it to be constantly ini the same place like the image above).

**How can I make the div stay in the same place like in the image?**

Here is what I currently have:

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr) );
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 95px;
  /* 25 */
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-left: 215px;
  margin-bottom: 170px;

  text-align: center;
}

#example {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 130px;

   padding: 5px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 2px solid red;
   color: darkgreen;
}

.grid-item:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.grid-item:hover {

background-color: #262626;
}

.grid-item {
  position: relative;

padding: 0px;

  border-radius: 10px;

  transition: 0.2s background-color;
}

.thumbnail {
  /* background-color: black; */
  /* object-fit: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; */

  margin-right: 5px;
  /* width: 95%; */
  width: 430px;
  height: 240px;
  /* height: 70%; */
  border-radius: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #282828;
  cursor: pointer;
  object-fit: cover;
}
/* object-fit: cover; */

.details {
  display: inline-flex;
  /* text-align: center; */
  /* display:block; */
  /* display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle; */

  /* background-color: grey; */
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* width: 95%; */
  width: 430px;
  height: 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.portalTitle {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* margin: auto; */
  /* line-height: 70px; */
  font: Arial;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight:500;
}
.profileImg {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
    <div class="content">
      <div class="grid-item">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/soundscapeportals.appspot.com/o/9SUaEJqwrbYHv0kyGmAhglyY1eI2%2F8a53b262101685.5a84bec504f01.jpg?alt=media&token=ea80efb6-a7e7-41d6-9c2d-cdc5ef8cc731">
        <div id="example">This is my div</div>
        <div class="details">
          <img class="profileImg" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/soundscapeportals.appspot.com/o/9SUaEJqwrbYHv0kyGmAhglyY1eI2%2F8a53b262101685.5a84bec504f01.jpg?alt=media&token=ea80efb6-a7e7-41d6-9c2d-cdc5ef8cc731">
          <span class="portalTitle"> Shanghai, China night sounds</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="images/testImg.png">
        <div id="example">This is my div</div>
        <div class="details">
          <img class="profileImg" src="images/testImg.png">
          <span class="portalTitle"> Shanghai, China night sounds</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put your image inside a container div and make your example be positioned absolute to that div, not the griditem div. Also, DO NOT use multiple elements with the same ID. Here is an example where I made the first item be like you want it to be and your second one is how you originally had it so you can see the difference.

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr) );
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 95px;
  /* 25 */
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-left: 215px;
  margin-bottom: 170px;
  text-align: center;
}

.example {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 130px;
   padding: 5px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 2px solid red;
   color: darkgreen;
}

.grid-item:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.grid-item:hover {
  background-color: #262626;
}

.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s background-color;
}

.thumbnail {
  /* background-color: black; */
  /* object-fit: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; */
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* width: 95%; */
  width: 430px;
  height: 240px;
  /* height: 70%; */
  border-radius: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #282828;
  cursor: pointer;
  object-fit: cover;
}
/* object-fit: cover; */

.details {
  display: inline-flex;
  /* text-align: center; */
  /* display:block; */
  /* display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle; */
  /* background-color: grey; */
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* width: 95%; */
  width: 430px;
  height: 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.portalTitle {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* margin: auto; */
  /* line-height: 70px; */
  font: Arial;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight:500;
}
.profileImg {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.imgcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/soundscapeportals.appspot.com/o/9SUaEJqwrbYHv0kyGmAhglyY1eI2%2F8a53b262101685.5a84bec504f01.jpg?alt=media&token=ea80efb6-a7e7-41d6-9c2d-cdc5ef8cc731" />
      <div class="example">This is my div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <img class="profileImg" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/soundscapeportals.appspot.com/o/9SUaEJqwrbYHv0kyGmAhglyY1eI2%2F8a53b262101685.5a84bec504f01.jpg?alt=media&token=ea80efb6-a7e7-41d6-9c2d-cdc5ef8cc731" />
      <span class="portalTitle"> Shanghai, China night sounds</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="images/testImg.png" />
    <div class="example">This is my div</div>
    <div class="details">
      <img class="profileImg" src="images/testImg.png" />
      <span class="portalTitle"> Shanghai, China night sounds</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```